# Locals windows can't appear

Tags: vb.net

I am using `VisualStudio 2012` and `VisualStudio` does not showing window for local variables while debugging. 
Please refer to following image 
[image]

Comment: I wanted to be the first to congratulate you on the 111,111th question asked on vb.net. It looks truly binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open the Locals window, you must be debugging. From the `Debug` menu, choose `Windows`, and then choose `Locals`.

Answer (score 0):

Hit `Start` and begin debugging. Once you're in Debug mode you should be able to go to Debug -> Windows -> Locals

Like this
[image]

This Window won't be available in the context menu until you are in Debug mode